# create matching label with periodic repeating values

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, for-loop, lambda, apply

I have data like the input data data_df2 sample below.  I have the code below that creates the label column by comparing the Cleaned column value to the value in the record before it and then either giving it the same letter, if the values match, or a new value.  The problem I have is that I would like the letters that are chosen for the label column to start over with every new label_set_id.  So the label value for first label_set_id=2 would be A.  Every 20 records the label_set_id goes up by 1.  Can anyone suggest how I can modify the code below to accomplish this?  Or is there a slicker way with pandas, say using the apply function.  This code does run kind of slow.

code:

```
data_df2['label']=''


c=65
data_df2.label[0]=chr(c)

c=c+1

for i in range(1,len(data_df2)):
    if(data_df2.loc[i,'Cleaned']==data_df2.loc[i-1,'Cleaned']):
        data_df2.label[i]=data_df2.label[i-1]

    else:

        data_df2.label[i]=chr(c)


        c=c+1
```

input data:

```
print(data_df2[:30])

    id                                    Source  \
0    1                                ,O-PEN 2.0   
1    2  .7 FRAM BLOWER - BROTHERLY LOVE MECHANIC   
2    3                           @BEEZLEEXTRACTS   
3    4                              @CALISIFTCO_   
4    5                @CALISIFTCO_ X @_ZKITTLEZ_   
5    6               @CALISIFTCO_ X @WONDERBRETT   
6    7              @CALISIFTCO_ X @WONDERBRETT_   
7    8                             @DNA_GENETICS   
8    9                          @EDENEXTRACTS_CA   
9   10           @EDENEXTRACTS_CA X @CALISIFTCO_   
10  11                         @FULLFLAVAEXTRACT   
11  12                                @GGSTRAINS   
12  13                            @SHERBINSKI415   
13  14          @STR8MECHANIC X @ICEDOUTEXTRACTS   
14  15              @STR8MECHANIC X @REZHEADS215   
15  16                             [SS] 710 LABS   
16  17                    [SS] ABSOLUTE EXTRACTS   
17  18                           [SS] BIG PETE'S   
18  19                          [SS] BLOOM FARMS   
19  20                           [SS] BLUE RIVER   
20  21                           [SS] BRITE LABS   
21  22                       [SS] BROTHERLY LOVE   
22  23              [SS] BROTHERLY LOVE [3 PACK]   
23  24                   [SS] CALIFORNIA DREAMIN   
24  25                             [SS] DIME BAG   
25  26                       [SS] EDEN INFUSIONS   
26  27                            [SS] EEL RIVER   
27  28                           [SS] GANJA GOLD   
28  29                       [SS] GLOWING BUDDHA   
29  30                                [SS] JETTY   

                         Cleaned  label_set_id label  
0                     O.PEN VAPE             1     A  
1                 BROTHERLY LOVE             1     B  
2                BEEZLE EXTRACTS             1     C  
3                   CALI SIFT CO             1     D  
4                   CALI SIFT CO             1     D  
5   @CALISIFTCO_ X @WONDERBRETT_             1     E  
6   @CALISIFTCO_ X @WONDERBRETT_             1     E  
7                   DNA GENETICS             1     F  
8                           EDEN             1     G  
9                   CALI SIFT CO             1     H  
10                       FLAV RX             1     I  
11                    GG STRAINS             1     J  
12                    SHERBINSKI             1     K  
13                 STR8 MECHANIC             1     L  
14                 STR8 MECHANIC             1     L  
15                      710 LABS             1     M  
16              ABSOLUTE XTRACTS             1     N  
17             BIG PETE'S TREATS             1     O  
18                   BLOOM FARMS             1     P  
19                    BLUE RIVER             1     Q  
20                    BRITE LABS             2     R  
21                BROTHERLY LOVE             2     S  
22                BROTHERLY LOVE             2     S  
23            CALIFORNIA DREAMIN             2     T  
24                      DIME BAG             2     U  
25                          EDEN             2     V  
26                     EEL RIVER             2     W  
27                    GANJA GOLD             2     X  
28                GLOWING BUDDHA             2     Y  
29                JETTY EXTRACTS             2     Z
```

output data:

```
    id                                    Source  \
0    1                                ,O-PEN 2.0   
1    2  .7 FRAM BLOWER - BROTHERLY LOVE MECHANIC   
2    3                           @BEEZLEEXTRACTS   
3    4                              @CALISIFTCO_   
4    5                @CALISIFTCO_ X @_ZKITTLEZ_   
5    6               @CALISIFTCO_ X @WONDERBRETT   
6    7              @CALISIFTCO_ X @WONDERBRETT_   
7    8                             @DNA_GENETICS   
8    9                          @EDENEXTRACTS_CA   
9   10           @EDENEXTRACTS_CA X @CALISIFTCO_   
10  11                         @FULLFLAVAEXTRACT   
11  12                                @GGSTRAINS   
12  13                            @SHERBINSKI415   
13  14          @STR8MECHANIC X @ICEDOUTEXTRACTS   
14  15              @STR8MECHANIC X @REZHEADS215   
15  16                             [SS] 710 LABS   
16  17                    [SS] ABSOLUTE EXTRACTS   
17  18                           [SS] BIG PETE'S   
18  19                          [SS] BLOOM FARMS   
19  20                           [SS] BLUE RIVER   
20  21                           [SS] BRITE LABS   
21  22                       [SS] BROTHERLY LOVE   
22  23              [SS] BROTHERLY LOVE [3 PACK]   
23  24                   [SS] CALIFORNIA DREAMIN   
24  25                             [SS] DIME BAG   
25  26                       [SS] EDEN INFUSIONS   
26  27                            [SS] EEL RIVER   
27  28                           [SS] GANJA GOLD   
28  29                       [SS] GLOWING BUDDHA   
29  30                                [SS] JETTY   

                         Cleaned  label_set_id label  
0                     O.PEN VAPE             1     A  
1                 BROTHERLY LOVE             1     B  
2                BEEZLE EXTRACTS             1     C  
3                   CALI SIFT CO             1     D  
4                   CALI SIFT CO             1     D  
5   @CALISIFTCO_ X @WONDERBRETT_             1     E  
6   @CALISIFTCO_ X @WONDERBRETT_             1     E  
7                   DNA GENETICS             1     F  
8                           EDEN             1     G  
9                   CALI SIFT CO             1     H  
10                       FLAV RX             1     I  
11                    GG STRAINS             1     J  
12                    SHERBINSKI             1     K  
13                 STR8 MECHANIC             1     L  
14                 STR8 MECHANIC             1     L  
15                      710 LABS             1     M  
16              ABSOLUTE XTRACTS             1     N  
17             BIG PETE'S TREATS             1     O  
18                   BLOOM FARMS             1     P  
19                    BLUE RIVER             1     Q  
20                    BRITE LABS             2     A  
21                BROTHERLY LOVE             2     B  
22                BROTHERLY LOVE             2     B  
23            CALIFORNIA DREAMIN             2     C  
24                      DIME BAG             2     D  
25                          EDEN             2     E  
26                     EEL RIVER             2     F  
27                    GANJA GOLD             2     G  
28                GLOWING BUDDHA             2     H  
29                JETTY EXTRACTS             2     I
```

Comment: Your input and output looks the same to me. Did i miss something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, you can use `groupby` on label_set_id and check where two following rows are different with `shift`, and use `cumsum` to get an incremental value per group. Add 64 for `map` the `chr` function.

```
#dummy example
df = pd.DataFrame({'Cleaned':list('abbcddeffijkllmn'), 
                   'label_set_id':[1]*8+[2]*8})

#create the column label
df['label'] = list(map(chr, df.groupby('label_set_id')['Cleaned']\
                              .apply(lambda x: x.ne(x.shift()).cumsum())+64))

print (df)
   Cleaned  label_set_id label
0        a             1     A
1        b             1     B 
2        b             1     B #same cleaned than previous row 
3        c             1     C
4        d             1     D
5        d             1     D
6        e             1     E
7        f             1     F
8        f             2     A #restart at A for new label_set_id
9        i             2     B
10       j             2     C
11       k             2     D
12       l             2     E
13       l             2     E
14       m             2     F
15       n             2     G
```

EDIT: if the data is ordered in terms of label_set_id, you can do it without groupby:

```
df['label'] = df['Cleaned'].ne(df['Cleaned'].shift()) .cumsum()
df['label'] = list(map(chr, df['label']
                            -df['label'].where(df['label_set_id'].ne(df['label_set_id'].shift()))\
                                        .ffill().astype(int) + 65 ))
```

Comment: Thank you!  That is an awesome solution and way faster.

Comment: @user3476463 if the label_set_id is ordered (as it seems to be according to your question) see the EDIT, it maybe be faster